# AngularJs link function and Jquery manipulation. Code doesn't seem to work

Tags: jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a login modal in a directive which I am trying to make it work using link function and jquery but it doesn't seem to work.

- This is the login button

  ```
  <button login-modal type="button" class="btn">Sign In</button>
  ```
- This is the smaller version of the login modal view

  ```
  <div id="loginModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog"></div>
  ```
- This is the login directive

  ```
  angular
      .module('app')
      .directive('loginModal', ['$scope', loginModalDirective]);


      function loginModalDirective($scope) {
      return {
          restrict: 'E',
          templateUrl: 'template/loginmodal.view.html',
          link: function(scope, elem, attr) {
              elem.on('click', function() {
                  jQuery("#loginModal").modal();
              });
          }
      };
  }
  ```

Comment: You should seriously consider using AngularJS for handling events instead of jQuery. For instance, instead of doing `elem.on('click'` use the `ng-click` directive.

Comment: That's actually a good idea Mike but I have a part on my website where I'll be using tons of the same modal and I thought this way might be better. I am new to angular though so I might even be wrong.

Comment: @S.Patel That actually a reason that you _should_ be using Angular. You can define a modal template (including a view and controller) just the same as you would for a full state and then pass it around to anything that needs to call up an instance of it. I'd recommend the [Angular Bootstrap modal](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/modal).

Comment: @HarrisWeinstein OMG! TY SO MUCH

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have the restriction to `E`, which means element. Your element is `button`. Your directive is not being initialized.

Use `A` for attribute, since `login-modal` is an attribute.

```
restrict: 'A'
```

Also (not a problem, just waste), you don't use `$scope` and there's no need to inject into the directive. You get `scope` in the link method already.